# How can I take "Photo Sphere" style images with a regular camera?

Tags: digital, 360-panorama

With google's Nexus devices it is possible to make so-called [Photo Spheres](https://www.google.com/maps/about/contribute/photosphere/).

Is it possible to make a Photo Sphere with an ordinary digital camera?

Comment: A link towards the bottom of that page [Using Your Own Camera](http://photo-sphere.appspot.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just found out that all one needs is the Google Camera app. Thus, eg Samsung Galaxy NX, which runs Android should do the job, without any extra afterworks.

Comment: You also need a device with an accelerometer (which the Galaxy NX does, but isn't _necessarily_ the case with all Android devices).

Comment: Ok @mattdm, noted